# The meaning of "bear away the empty cup on the knee"

Tags: meaning

> 'The King turned to the tables, and held him out his own cup of wine.
>   The old man drank, and beckoned behind him, and, before all the
>   Normans, my Hugh **bore away** the empty cup, Saxon-fashion, **upon
>   the knee**.

This is from "The Tree of Justice" in *Rewards and Fairies* by Kipling.

http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/treejustice.html

I do not understand the meaning of below.

bear away the empty cup on the knee
Because the old man  and Hugh are both standing.

I am so glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 5):

The old man gestures to Hugh to take the cup from him, and Hugh--who recognizes the old man as Harold Godwinson, the English king defeated and dethroned forty years before at Hastings--kneels to receive the cup from him, and still on his knees carries it away from him. The next line of the story confirms this:

> “It is Harold!” said De Aquila. “His own stiff-necked blood kneels to serve him.”

Comment: StoneyB,thank you so much for your answer. I understand the meaning.